# Could you please the correct header type for ISO8583 authorization(0100) msg?

Tags: java, serversocket, iso8583, j8583

I am implementing the custom ISO8583 protocol using socket in spring boot with below dependency we have passed all the required data elements with correct length

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.j8583</groupId>
        <artifactId>j8583</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and my xml file looks like below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE j8583-config PUBLIC "-//J8583//DTD CONFIG 1.0//EN" "http://j8583.sourceforge.net/j8583.dtd">
<j8583-config>

    <!-- These are the ISO headers to be prepended to the message types specified -->
    <header type="0200">ISO015000050</header>
    <header type="0210">ISO015000055</header>
    <header type="0400">ISO015000050</header>
    <header type="0410">ISO015000055</header>
    <header type="0800">ISO015000015</header>
    <header type="0810">ISO015000015</header>
    <header type="0100">ISO015000050</header>
    <header type="0110">ISO015000055</header>



    <template type="0100">
        <!-- Membership Number -->
        <field num="2" type="LLVAR" length="19"></field>
        <!-- Transaction Amount -->
        <field num = "4" type="NUMERIC" length="12"></field>
        <!-- Expiration Date -->
        <field num="14" type="NUMERIC" length="4"/>
        <!-- Merchant Category Code -->
        <field num="18" type="NUMERIC" length="4"></field>
        <!-- Acquiring Institution country Code -->
        <field num="19" type="NUMERIC" length="3"></field>
        <!-- Acquiring Institution ID Code -->
        <field num="32" type="NUMERIC" length="6"></field>
        <!-- Terminal ID -->
        <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="8"></field>
        <!-- Merchant ID -->
        <field num="42" type="ALPHA" length="15"></field>
        <!-- Merchant Name and Location -->
        <field num="43" type="LLVAR" length="40"></field>
        <!-- Transaction Currency Code -->
        <field num="49" type="NUMERIC" length="3"/>
        <!-- Transaction Fee Amount-->
        <field num="28" type="NUMERIC" length="9"/>

    </template>
    


    <!-- Transaction Request 100 -->

    <parse type="0100">
        <!-- Membership Number -->
        <field num="2" type="LLVAR" length="19"></field>
        <!-- Transaction Amount -->
        <field num = "4" type="NUMERIC" length="12"></field>
        <!-- Expiration Date -->
        <field num="14" type="NUMERIC" length="4"/>
        <!-- Merchant Category Code -->
        <field num="18" type="NUMERIC" length="4"></field>
        <!-- Acquiring Institution country Code -->
        <field num="19" type="NUMERIC" length="3"></field>
        <!-- Acquiring Institution ID Code -->
        <field num="32" type="NUMERIC" length="11"></field>
        <!-- Terminal ID -->
        <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="8"/>
        <!-- Merchant ID -->
        <field num="42" type="ALPHA" length="15"></field>
        <!-- Merchant Name and Location -->
        <field num="43" type="LLVAR" length="40"></field>
        <!-- Transaction Currency Code -->
        <field num="49" type="NUMERIC" length="3"/>
        <!-- Transaction Fee Amount-->
        <field num="28" type="NUMERIC" length="8"/>


    </parse>

    <!-- Transaction Response 110  -->

    <parse type="0110">
        <!-- Membership Number -->
        <field num="2" type="LLVAR" length="19"></field>
        <!-- Transaction Amount -->
        <field num = "4" type="NUMERIC" length="12"></field>
        <!-- Expiration Date -->
        <field num="14" type="DATE4" length="4"/>
        <!-- Merchant Category Code -->
        <field num="18" type="NUMERIC" length="4"></field>
        <!-- Acquiring Institution country Code -->
        <field num="19" type="NUMERIC" length="3"></field>
        <!-- Acquiring Institution ID Code -->
        <field num="32" type="NUMERIC" length="11"></field>
        <!-- Terminal ID -->
        <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="8"/>
        <!-- Merchant ID -->
        <field num="42" type="ALPHA" length="15"></field>
        <!-- Transaction Currency Code -->
        <field num="49" type="NUMERIC" length="3"/>
        <!-- Transaction Fee Amount-->
        <field num="28" type="NUMERIC" length="8"/>
        <!-- Merchant Name and Location -->

    </parse>
    
</j8583-config>
```

whenever we tried to send the sample ISO message on server we are getting below error.

**Insufficient data for LLVAR header, pos 118**

Comment: Could you post the binary data being sent to the server and the code you are using to construct the message?